# Podcast/Step by step turorials like those of after effects and Photoshop where you strip away the layers

Tags: podcasts

Podcast/Step by step turorials like those of after effects and Photoshop where you strip away the layers.

Sound Design could really benefit from something like that.

Especially from someone who chooses the more "bizarre" sounds like Randy Thom.

Comment: i could be into that.  any specific effect you're looking to hear dissected?

Comment: Hey @Rene, I want to know how you make wind without having any wind to record! hehehe

Comment: Like from step one to choosing the sounds, say why they were chosen, procssiong, mixing, etc...its just great to be able to share the knowledge.  One of the reasons video community advances so rapidly is due to shared knowledge be it school or forums.  Sound is full of mystery and secret and people have yet to fully open up in the same way

Answer (score 1):

About Utopia's question of how to wind without wind: I cant't find the videos right now, but I remember Ben Burtt dragging a rolled-up carpet down the hall for a wind sound in Wall-E. And Gary Rydstrom just going "whoooo" into a mic in the opening scene of Terminator 2. Actually there are many ways to sweeten or even create wind sounds I think, because there are so many types of wind. Recently I've used pitched down chair screeches as wind sounds. It's great when you can go wild with those things... ;)

Comment: ah, just saw that utopia's question is more like a running gag it seems? :) saw your kleenex-wind recording, nice...

Answer (score 0):

I've actually thought of this pretty often. There is a dude (i think nickstutorials) on youtube that had something similar for some sound redesigns he did while trying to learn, and they were pretty good and informative. I've considered trying to do some of these, but I don't consider myself an authority on it, and I don't feel as comfortable really. At least yet. I was still pretty shocked at the dearth of stuff like that that there was when i was looking around.

I feel like the answer is ALWAYS "Well, just experiment!" ....yea...of course experiment, however, being able to see how other people experiment just makes your game improve exponentially and faster. Could you imagine us learning how to mix only ever reading books and articles and never setting foot in front of a daw/studio? Good post though, i'll be following this.